# ASP.NET Core 8 is missing from application pool selection after install

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-8.0

We have installed .NET 8.0 Hosting Bundle but when we go to change an application pool to enable it, it is missing from the list. How do we get this to appear?

It is also not under ISAPI and CGI Restrictions so may this be why? The path to .NET 8 seems to be different to 2 and 4 and where it is located there is no `aspnet_isapi.dll` to map to.

Installing .NET8 and the option being available under application pools.

Answer (score 1):

It is intended that .NET Core versions and higher - e.g. .NET 8 - don't appear in the list for configuring the .NET CLR version setting, since the .NET CLR is not being used by ASP.NET Core and upwards.

It is recommend to set No Managed Code.

[image]

See step 6 in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-8.0#create-the-iis-site) (version ASP.NET Core in .NET 8.0):

> In the **Edit Application Pool** window, set the **.NET CLR version** to **No Managed Code**

> ASP.NET Core runs in a separate process and manages the runtime. ASP.NET Core  doesn't rely on loading the desktop CLR (.NET CLR). The Core Common Language Runtime (CoreCLR) for .NET Core is booted to host the app in the worker process.
> Setting the .NET CLR version to No Managed Code is optional but recommended.